# PostgreSQL and Perl: violates foreign key constraint

Tags: postgresql, perl

I have table lv and referenced table pozemek, that contains:

```
"pozemek_lv_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (lv_id) REFERENCES lv(id)
```

and I want create record in lv and subsequently in pozemek:

```
my $lv_ins = $kadadbh->prepare("INSERT INTO lv ...");
my $poz_ins= $kadadbh->prepare("INSERT INTO pozemek (lv_id,...) VALUES (?,...)");
$lv_ins->execute(...);
$lv_id = $kadadbh->last_insert_id(undef,undef,'lv','id');
print "lv_id=$lv_id\n";
$poz_ins->execute($lv_id,...);
```

It returns a new lv_id, but consequently fails:

> lv_id=8990
>
> ERROR:  insert or update on table "pozemek" violates foreign key constraint "pozemek_lv_id_fkey"
>
> DETAIL:  Key (lv_id)=(8990) is not present in table "lv". at ./dznxml.pl line 121

Comment: What's in line 121? You should [edit] your question and include the SQL CREATE statements for those two tables.

Comment: Create a self contained example that exhibits your problem. You posted an edited excerpt, from which it is not possible to see what is wrong.